# Retrieving a string from array of string const

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

How do I get the string representation if I know the enum of integer value ?

```
type    
  MyEnum = (tmp_one, tmp_two, tmp_three);

const
  MyTypeNames: array[tmp_one..tmp_three] of string = ('One', 'Two', 'Three');
```

Comment: It is customary to name your types starting with `T`, like `TMyEnum`. Also, the members of the enum should be like `meOne, meTwo, meThree`. [Compare: `TFontStyle = (fsBold, fsItalic, fsUnderline, fsStrikeOut); TWindowState = (wsNormal, wsMinimized, wsMaximized)` etc.]

Comment: The question is unclear to me. I can only make assumptions of what the OP wants...

Comment: @kobik - I agree. I don't understand what does "knowing an enum of integer" mean? And also what does string representation mean, "tmp_one" or "One"?

Comment: Sorry the question was so unclear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have an ordinal value rather than a variable of this enumerated type. If so then you just need to cast the ordinal to the enumerated type. Like this:

```
function GetNameFromOrdinal(Ordinal: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := MyTypeNames[MyEnum(Ordinal)]; 
end;
```

Comment: IMHO it is a bit overkill with a function. But of course you could argue that it is for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Why not just pass in a `MyEnum` parameter and avoid the typecast? The types are hard-coded already.

Comment: @Ken: I believe David took notice of the 'if I know the enum of integer value' part of the question.

Comment: @Andreas I made it a function because that's just an easy way to be explicit about the types of parameter and return value

Answer (score 6):

I assume you want to use the names in your array of string. Then this is very simple:

```
var
  myEnumVar: MyEnum;
begin
  myEnumVar := tmp_two; // For example
  ShowMessage(MyTypeNames[myEnumVar]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use the ordinal values of your enum type. You can declare an array with the enum type as its "subscript" and use an enum var directly.

```
type    
  TMyEnum = (tmp_one, tmp_two, tmp_three);

const
  MyTypeNames: array[TMyEnum] of string = ('One', 'Two', 'Three');

function Enum2Text(aEnum: TMyEnum): string;
begin
  Result := MyTypeNames[aEnum]; 
end;
```

Call it with the enum or an integer value cast to the enum:

```
Enum2Text(tmp_one);     // -> 'One'
Enum2Text(TMyEnum(2));  // -> 'Three'
```